# How to convert hex string into a bytes array, and a bytes array in the hex string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, hex

The following code procedure **bytes = parseHexString (createHexString (bytes))** leads **to updated of bytes**, what I would like to avoid. And as a result calculations are not correct.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT SRC="http://eu.static.mega.co.nz/sjcl_1.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="http://eu.static.mega.co.nz/crypto_1.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="http://eu.static.mega.co.nz/rsa_1.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="http://eu.static.mega.co.nz/hex_1.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
function parseHexString(str) { 
    var result = [];
    while (str.length >= 2) { 
        result.push(parseInt(str.substring(0, 2), 16));
        str = str.substring(2, str.length);
    }

    return result;
}

function createHexString(arr) {
    var result = "";
    for (i in arr) {
        var str = arr[i].toString(16);
        str = str.length == 0 ? "00" :
              str.length == 1 ? "0" + str : 
              str.length == 2 ? str :
              str.substring(str.length-2, str.length);
        result += str;
    }
    return result;
}

function t()
{
    var json_k     = 'aOrP5yLtNQT53WMQfufSlA';
    var json_csid  = 'CABD6JUMldvI_eqP0537xl9P8x7kgk2OjOq99Fy7kosphj6AFUtlbwRRDpg4EIifXRLO6FNpdD22WwtUlJ_1Mgye2Y87trEqLCbhahuEFJVQNMDtNbIem7xY2ER9uF-cdgBXZWuzp7XIBybSh7W8MSUlv_eGS6LcLGJ81Q49dSzVhcswHTJ_IJl04p3c0axR6ZIJ8dH5bJ_vXvgQsypUVVtdfMacKhB9cXdEtRZ6iWLKCKqscXdo6CNXlbIdzRhro0gxfmhfB_miysFAiSQrbtuYnIgYBU3i9p3jRlPD4ti3CUcnj0SomV61w1aEYNvo56HPMUZlVkVHA7BFzvHGHo0J';
    var json_privk = 'K7LDtk2M2QhjJx_v_Hqf0LKUBaZx76U_vBDjQty9HpFDy2MntF5HxxuyHQ9-1HmXeYzbL1pZnAxsZ7LRUbDnkR6qtJVaGdWuQhrytkuq0l5zBp-O--gZxoQPRGTsVgVRdAvpsRTkQI_q8fxADLCe0womFxtvvnD_FJgjaMsm7vkYchXkoq33WWyHijb3JMkymjl0_GtiSamT0qEL6sm_l5Z1lehqBGUEHfYAa0ub8IDx_yqy2R9Nh8Lwzmz4s24sShVxjaNsMBlSE-sEvTziOsnNWK1Zl_XUYadlENkweuIoxYx_lt8XIV71TzjEFuVTd-pXhzVlqePmIu3SM3bO1Kzq_DnGfB62RmzlmbtHU4iyw4Hd1wQFRhTeSRrvMjsMPFKN-SIIQU7CRNaMuaDxZbNZcOKhMg_h9mApM0rRS3VZaGZzFTL9rSaDMYHw4pL3aOkSFPMY3w785Tss7Zqwuo9HFUWUVbnYAb97JkgCohlMotORrMMtual1dQ4sG1sIYXyWTckAGGL0ZAGurhtSKiyz1m8Lb39pXPacqFh_nCHqqb2_RdrKTj0PdGZESKkU8YedeqC1I9nR4v38DuQc-pBBR5DOwgNjJMvzvsUehs_PxIL8THjgIcr7ONc4hWV9o2v_l81Vo2cCW2I99Iz84IFN2fV1dTqHIG_tnLzz8ljBVygETUqrFdZ0JlQJkurZ7RBku5krm-k9CZmDezCIzPPil-RcYzVIk00gNYAxfiZE48Or4WEiGjgKLnHCYVtSlvlMF4bPGB4SVCZ-68j49EjfSWaMK0OoMkpGhqf7KchgxYBZq6o3AhLgp4t0BClvsdee6VTz1SFqc3m2A-TMG6fNdbCT_Q9nYCYdZIROdOc';

    var aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes( prepare_key_pw("oEyoo9cQcw") );
    k = decrypt_key(aes, base64_to_a32(json_k) );

    aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes(k);

    var t = mpi2b(base64urldecode(json_csid));

    var privk = a32_to_str(decrypt_key(aes,base64_to_a32(json_privk)));

    var rsa_privk = Array(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var l = ((privk.charCodeAt(0)*256+privk.charCodeAt(1)+7)>>3)+2;

        rsa_privk[i] = mpi2b(privk.substr(0,l));
        if (typeof rsa_privk[i] == 'number') break;
        privk = privk.substr(l);    
    }

    var p = parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[0]));  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var q = parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[1]));  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var d = parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[2]));  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var u = parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[3]));  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    sid = base64urlencode(b2s(RSAdecrypt(t,d,p,q,u)).substr(0,43));
    if (sid!=='tajetAbW0qTQGFlwp8iD5lQ0TFV1QUZJZFVvjRX7Xx-bPzYBoau7qog09w')
        console.log("ERROR");

    p = rsa_privk[0];
    q = rsa_privk[1];
    d = rsa_privk[2];
    u = rsa_privk[3];
    sid = base64urlencode(b2s(RSAdecrypt(t,d,p,q,u)).substr(0,43));
    if (sid=='tajetAbW0qTQGFlwp8iD5lQ0TFV1QUZJZFVvjRX7Xx-bPzYBoau7qog09w')
        console.log("OK");
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="t();"></body>
</html>
```

I am not javascript developer, and not one found in google code did not work **on this data**.

**Update 1**

```
console.log(createHexString(rsa_privk[0])); = e5d109c673d8ef03df564beb9e36e9983a23842b0a724efa45ff76bbe5ad72ed62d2757968
```

But if do

```
parseHexString('e5d109c673d8ef03df564beb9e36e9983a23842b0a724efa45ff76bbe5ad72ed‌​62d2757968');
```

then code `if (sid!== ...` make error

**Update 2**

```
console.log(rsa_privk[0].toString(16));
```

output:
    123676133,198914513,129998601,245147334,11918451,206998232,96766191,75984899,177840095,106709334,10180427,208237547,119814814,127003446,189062377,84099480,220452154,250519075,267883908,115471915,165124106,238628722,169382478,42320122,95982405,80725759,89608310,85166267,200925925,254033325,86971506,191278317,127411298,180195794,142776693,188738169,39016

**Update 3**

```
console.log(parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[0])));
console.log(rsa_privk[0]);
```

output:

```
[229, 209, 9, 198, 115, 216, 239, 3, 223, 86, 75, 235, 158, 54, 233, 152, 58, 35, 132, 43, 10, 114, 78, 250, 69, 255, 118, 187, 229, 173, 114, 237, 98, 210, 117, 121, 104]

[123676133, 198914513, 129998601, 245147334, 11918451, 206998232, 96766191, 75984899, 177840095, 106709334, 10180427, 208237547, 119814814, 127003446, 189062377, 84099480, 220452154, 250519075, 267883908, 115471915, 165124106, 238628722, 169382478, 42320122, 95982405, 80725759, 89608310, 85166267, 200925925, 254033325, 86971506, 191278317, 127411298, 180195794, 142776693, 188738169, 39016]
```

Comment: What data are you expecting and what data are you getting?

Comment: I expect that the transformation data = parseHexString (createHexString (data)) not change the data

Comment: Copy paste your input to `createHexString(rsa_privk[0])`, ie `console.log(rsa_privk[0]);`.

Comment: console.log(createHexString(rsa_privk[0]));  = e5d109c673d8ef03df564beb9e36e9983a23842b0a724efa45ff76bbe5ad72ed62d2757968                But if do                                  parseHexString('e5d109c673d8ef03df564beb9e36e9983a23842b0a724efa45ff76bbe5ad72ed62d2757968');                     then code if                      (sid!== ...                      make error

Comment: See my updated answer, just add the `console.log` line and copy paste the whole output in your question.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, you want to just display the data as hex, right? Why do you need to convert it back?

Comment: Updated answer with solution... enjoy...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Update: Scroll down for solution... [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xnrq/)***

The issue: you are using a lossy conversion to hex, which cannot be reversed.

```
var p = parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[0]));
```

This will never be same as `rsa_privk[0]`.

Because, `createHexString()` only uses the `last 2 bytes` from each array element.

Example:

```
rsa_privk[0] : [123676133, 198914513, 129998601, 245147334, 11918451, 206998232, 96766191, 75984899, 177840095, 106709334, 10180427, 208237547, 119814814, 127003446, 189062377, 84099480, 220452154, 250519075, 267883908, 115471915, 165124106, 238628722, 169382478, 42320122, 95982405, 80725759, 89608310, 85166267, 200925925, 254033325, 86971506, 191278317, 127411298, 180195794, 142776693, 188738169, 39016]

createHexString(rsa_privk[0]) : e5d109c673d8ef03df564beb9e36e9983a23842b0a724efa45ff76bbe5ad72ed62d2757968

parseHexString(createHexString(rsa_privk[0])) : [229, 209, 9, 198, 115, 216, 239, 3, 223, 86, 75, 235, 158, 54, 233, 152, 58, 35, 132, 43, 10, 114, 78, 250, 69, 255, 118, 187, 229, 173, 114, 237, 98, 210, 117, 121, 104]
```

---

**Update : Working Solution...**

The two functions... the hex always contains 8 byte blocks, each for each element in the array...

```
function parseHexString(str) { 
    var result = [];
    while (str.length >= 8) { 
        result.push(parseInt(str.substring(0, 8), 16));

        str = str.substring(8, str.length);
    }

    return result;
}

function createHexString(arr) {
    var result = "";
    var z;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var str = arr[i].toString(16);

        z = 8 - str.length + 1;
        str = Array(z).join("0") + str;

        result += str;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Test code...

```
function test() {   
    a = [123676133, 198914513, 129998601, 245147334, 11918451, 206998232, 96766191, 75984899, 177840095, 106709334, 10180427, 208237547, 119814814, 127003446, 189062377, 84099480, 220452154, 250519075, 267883908, 115471915, 165124106, 238628722, 169382478, 42320122, 95982405, 80725759, 89608310, 85166267, 200925925, 254033325, 86971506, 191278317, 127411298, 180195794, 142776693, 188738169, 39016];

    console.log("Input");
    console.log(a);

    b = createHexString(a);

    console.log("Hex");
    console.log(b);

    c = parseHexString(b); 

    console.log("Output");
    console.log(c);

    if(checkIfEqual(a, c)) {
        alert("Same");
    }
}

function checkIfEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    //sort them first, then join them and just compare the strings
    return arr1.sort().join() == arr2.sort().join();
}
```

Comment: What is your input and output?

Comment: The data is in binary form in the code above. The question is how to display them in hex ​​format. But I'm sure not getting the correct result, because with inverse transformation data is not correctly.

Comment: What is your data like? Copy paste the data here.

Comment: data is binary, I can not insert here the binary data!!! they are calculated in the above code. And I do not know how to properly convert them to hex and back to binary

Comment: arr[i] gives back a character. what you want is the byte number from the character which you can get with .charCodeAt( ... )

Comment: What is your algorithm like? The current createHexString takes the last 2 bytes of the data given as input. Like for your example input, `123676133`, the function only takes `33`. Is this what you need in your algorithm?

Comment: @SkyN Please run this `console.log(rsa_privk[0]);` and paste output.

Comment: Creates ugly global variable z.

Comment: @PointerNull Just replace instance of z with its value.

Comment: Sure, I'm just pointing that your example code pollutes global namespace. You're missing one "var".

Answer (score 81):

**Convert a hex string to a byte array and vice versa**

*note: implementation from **crypto-js**, though now out of date and slightly altered*

```
// Convert a hex string to a byte array
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    let bytes = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
    return bytes;
}

// Convert a byte array to a hex string
function bytesToHex(bytes) {
    let hex = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        let current = bytes[i] < 0 ? bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
        hex.push((current >>> 4).toString(16));
        hex.push((current & 0xF).toString(16));
    }
    return hex.join("");
}
```

Comment: THIS works. Nothing else worked for me. Thank you SO much.

Comment: Just a reminder, crypto-js api has changed to CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(), there is no hexToBytes

Comment: The code has changed a little from the original. Here is the link to the latest bytesToHex (stringify) and hexToBytes (parse) methods: [crypto-js/core.js#L390](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/31d00127a7c87066c51abe56e7b8be3a32141cae/core.js#L390)

Comment: bytesToHex calculates strange on some circumtances. e.g. [159,15] is been calculated as '9f0f' it should be '9ff'. [25,255] does work again. Is this an endianess thing? The issues are beginning with 9th bit of the first array element. Function createHexString from the accepted answer works for me.

Comment: @TefoD I cannot reproduce your issue. the code works good to me

Comment: Whats wrong with just using `Buffer.toString("hex")` and `Buffer.from(str, "hex")`?

Comment: `substr` seems to be deprecated, but `substr(c, 2)` can be easily replaced by `substring(c, c + 2)`

Comment: @kravitz That only works in Node.

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to chime in that there is a library at https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js to easily help with conversions like this, and thus you don't need to write your own functions (which could possibly not be the most optimal, or be more optimal if your solution was reviewed through the open source community on GitHub).

```
var ByteBuffer = require("bytebuffer");

var bb = ByteBuffer.fromHex(yourHexString);

// need to convert it to base 64?
// bb.toBase64();
```

See https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js/wiki/API#bytebufferfromhexstr-littleendian-noassert for the API documention and more insight on the methods I used above.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, if you simply want to hex decode a simple string such as `48656C6C6F20576F726C6421` (`Hello World!`) you can use the OP function but instead of using a length of 8 you should use a length of 2.

Code:

```
var DecodeHexStringToByteArray = function (hexString) {
   var result = [];
   while (hexString.length >= 2) { 
       result.push(parseInt(hexString.substring(0, 2), 16));
       hexString = hexString.substring(2, hexString.length);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Output will be `[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]`

I know that this code is already in the OP question, but it's not in the accepted answer. My intent here is only to give a straight answer to the first part of the question being asked (`How to convert a hex string into a bytes array`).

Answer (score 3):

I found solution over here [enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/example/nodejs/string/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array.html)

```
function hexStringToByteArray(hexString) {
    if (hexString.length % 2 !== 0) {
        throw "Must have an even number of hex digits to convert to bytes";
    }
    var numBytes = hexString.length / 2;
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(numBytes);
    for (var i=0; i<numBytes; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = parseInt(hexString.substr(i*2, 2), 16);
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

once again thank you `http://www.java2s.com`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live sample for this test.

http://jsfiddle.net/vincentwang2020/eks1z4g2/

```
function testcreateHexString()
{
    alert('test function createHexString');
    var key = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];
    var result = createHexString(key);
    alert ('Hex value:' + result);

    alert('test function parseHexString');

    var key2 = parseHexString(result);

    if (key.sort().join() == key2.sort().join())
        alert ('Matched');

}
```