# How to encrypt jpeg on server using C# and decrypt it on browser using Crypt-JS

Tags: c#, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt jpeg on server and decrypt it on browser like below but failed at step #3.

1. Encrypt jpeg by C# on server
2. Get encrypted data, vector, and passphrase on client browser
3. Decrypt on client browser

I tried to things below, but nothing helped.

1. use RijndaelManaged instead of AesManaged on server.
2. use 'CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.parse' instead of 'CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse'
   on client.

Encryption on Server

```cs
public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes, string password, string vector)
{
    AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
    aes.KeySize = _keySize;
    aes.BlockSize = _blockSize;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vector);
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    byte[] encrypted = aes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    return encrypted;
}
```

Decryption on Client

```js
// These values are same as above
var encrypted = ... //  byte[]
var vector = ... // string
var password = ... // string

var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(vector),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var cipherText = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(encrypted);
var passwordWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, passwordWordArray, cipherParams);
// decrypted.words is empty here
```

Please advise.

I'm using .Net Core MVC 2.1, Crypto-JS 3.1.9-1, and Chrome74.0.3729.169 on Windows 10.

**THIS PROBLEM RESOLVED**

As Topaco mentioned, there was a flaw in javascript. The corrected code is as below.

```
var encrypted = ... //  byte[]
var vector = ... // string
var password = ... // string

var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(vector),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var cipherText = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(encrypted);
var cipherTextParam = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
            ciphertext: cipherText
        });
var passwordWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherTextParam, passwordWordArray, cipherParams);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check for AES padding related questions, they have problems where OP has trouble decrypting because the data being padded.

Comment: Have you heard of SSL ?

Comment: The easy way would be to require https.... Any other scheme makes you 'hide' the key somewhere, there are no good solutions for that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will check about padding and try another padding option.

Comment: I should have mentioned connection. I will use VPN, so connection will be secured. My goal is to store encrypted data on server and decrypt it on client. It is not to secure connection by AES.

Answer (score 1):

There are two flaws in the JavaScript-code that can be corrected as follows:

- In the JavaScript-code the line:

  ```
  var cipherText = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(encrypted);
  ```

  must be replaced by:

  ```
  var cipherText = byteArrayToWordArray(encrypted);
  ```

  Here, the function [`byteArrayToWordArray`](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1) is used:

  ```
  function byteArrayToWordArray(ba) {
      var wa = [], i;
      for (i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) 
          wa[(i / 4) | 0] |= ba[i] << (24 - 8 * i);
      return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(wa, ba.length);
  }
  ```

  This function generates a word-array from the byte-array by generating a word (4 bytes) from 4 bytes of the byte-array. In the old code, a word of the same value is generated for each byte, i.e. both arrays have the same number of elements, which is wrong.

  Alternatively:

  ```
  var cipherTextHex = bytesToHex(encrypted);
  var cipherText = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipherTextHex);
  ```

  can also be used. Here, the function [`bytesToHex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356351/9014097) is used:

  ```
  function bytesToHex(bytes) {
      for (var hex = [], i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
          var current = bytes[i] < 0 ? bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
          hex.push((current >>> 4).toString(16));
          hex.push((current & 0xF).toString(16));
      }
      return hex.join("");
  }
  ```

  The function generates a hex-string from the byte-array. From this a word-array is derived using the appropriate [encoder](https://github.com/jakubzapletal/crypto-js#encoders).
- In the JavaScript-code, the line:

  ```
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, passwordWordArray, cipherParams);
  ```

  must be replaced by:

  ```
  var cipherParamsCipherText = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
      ciphertext: cipherText
  });
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParamsCipherText, passwordWordArray, cipherParams);
  ```

  since the `decrypted`-function expects a `CipherParams`-object as the first argument instead of a `WordArray`.

  Alternatively, a Base64-encoded string can also be passed:

  ```
  var cipherTextB64Enc = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(cipherText);   
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherTextB64Enc, passwordWordArray, cipherParams);
  ```
- Test: The C#-code provides for the following input:

  ```
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  string password = "0123456789012345"; // 16 byte -> AES-128
  string vector = "5432109876543210";   // 16 byte
  ```

  the following byte-array as ciphertext:

  ```
  170, 27, 161, 209, 42, 247, 234, 191, 38, 167, 22, 74, 34, 139, 115, 0, 75, 207, 119, 161, 97, 142, 179, 93, 41, 12, 177, 128, 52, 151, 75, 231, 76, 157, 14, 197, 59, 111, 63, 206, 136, 218, 189, 244, 116, 43, 25, 20
  ```

  If the modified JavaScript-code is tested with those data:

  ```
  var encrypted = [170,27,161,209,42,247,234,191,38,167,22,74,34,139,115,0,75,207,119,161,97,142,179,93,41,12,177,128,52,151,75,231,76,157,14,197,59,111,63,206,136,218,189,244,116,43,25,20]; // byte[]
  var vector = "5432109876543210"    // string
  var password = "0123456789012345"; // string
  ```

  it is decrypted correctly.

  In the test AES-128 has been used. It can be switched to AES-256 by simply using a 32-byte key instead of a 16-byte key.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. Your second point helped! Actually, I tried "byteArrayToWordArray" before and observed that the function and "CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create" returns the same result.