# nativescript-nfc rfid reader plugin unique id issue

Tags: unique, nfc, uniqueidentifier, reader

I use the nfc reader and Im able to get the unique id of the tags. When I read the tag the id is called like this:

> id: [ -52, 22, -61, -67, 80, 1, 4, -32, [length]: 8 ]

How can I get the hexadecimal one? It should be called CC:16:C3:BD:50:01:04:E0. That's also the way I will have database entries. So the way I get the id back is somehow useless for me.

I will appreciate any helpful answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of byte is -128 to 127

e.g. For Java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

"byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)."

You just need to convert that to display as a String as Hex.

Usually According to ISO/IEC 14443-3 the UID is a 7 byte Number with byte 4 being part of the check bytes

I don't know how to convert bytes to string in Nativescript but in Java you can do

```java
StringBuilder Uid = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        // byte 4 is a check byte
                        if (i == 3) continue;
                        Uid.append(String.format("%02X ", result[i]));
                    }
```

While skipping the check byte is not totally needed to give you an unique ID this code does it.

For JavaScript [How to convert hex string into a bytes array, and a bytes array in the hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603205/how-to-convert-hex-string-into-a-bytes-array-and-a-bytes-array-in-the-hex-strin) should provide the answer with a similar iterate over the array converting each byte to hex string

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it with this function // Convert a byte array to a hex string
function bytesToHex(bytes) {
    for (var hex = [], i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        var current = bytes[i] < 0 ? bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
        hex.push((current >>> 4).toString(16));
        hex.push((current & 0xF).toString(16));
    }
    return hex.join("");
}