# binaryDecode to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coldfusion

I'm trying to generate a key for decoding a password that has been encrypted using ColdFusion. Im getting different result when im passing param in `binaryDecode(string, "hex")`. How do I translate this into JavaScript?

in ColdFusion:

```
binaryDecode("CA993CED42F374C9291FC2484495CD9334E8C822", "hex")   
output is: -54-10360-1966-13116-554131-627268-107-51-10952-24-5634 (binary)  
after that the output will be looped and store in array variable 
then binaryEncode(javaCast("byte[]", arrayVariable), "Base64") 
the result is generatedKey



in Node js:
i didnt get the same output after the binaryDecode
43413939334345443432463337344339323931464332343834343935434439333334453843383232
I tried using `buffer.from()` but it just split to `43 41 39` etc.
```

I've tried so many things but I'm unable to get that `-54-10360-1966-13116-554131-627268-107-51-10952-24-5634` result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert hex string into a bytes array, and a bytes array in the hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603205/how-to-convert-hex-string-into-a-bytes-array-and-a-bytes-array-in-the-hex-strin)

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct ColdFusion code? You say that you are trying to "decode" a password but the `binaryDecode()` function is not used for encryption. It is used to convert string data back into binary data.

Comment: yes the return of binaryDecode will be used as a key for decoding encryption, but i just realize the CA993CED42F374C9291FC2484495CD9334E8C822 needs to be converted to hexadecimal bytes, then i need to BASE64 encoding, i notice from https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex, i just didnt understand what that binaryDecode did

Answer (score 2):

This is not coldfusion binaryDecode. More likely some output system just print in this format. Other words this is just convert `char` to `sbyte`.
But If you want try this code

```js
function convert(h) {
    h = h.split('');
    const r = [];
    for(let i=0; i<h.length; i+=2) {
        r.push(parseInt(h[i]+h[i+1], 16));
    }
    return r.map(e => e > 127 ? -(256-e): e).join('')
}


console.log(convert("CA993CED42F374C9291FC2484495CD9334E8C822"));
```

Comment: thanks, but i think i realize, where my problem is, i just need to change the CA993CED42F374C9291FC2484495CD9334E8C822 byte hex, and base64 encoding, i will update my solution

Answer (score 1):

i found what i was looking for

```
var btoa = require('btoa');

const  a= 'CA993CED42F374C9291FC2484495CD9334E8C822';
const f = Buffer.from(a, 'hex');
console.log(f);

const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(f)));

console.log(base64String);
```

thanks anyways for the help