# Compute HMACSHA256 in .net equivalent to reactjs

Tags: .net, reactjs, cryptography, cryptojs

I am migrating from .net core to reactjs and need to calculate hash. I stuck in this code where results are not equal. Here is the code of .net, _normKey and inputBytes are byte arrays and result stored in hash is also byte array. How can i convert this into reactjs.

```
    _normkey = [150, 68, 231, 118, 4, 194, 153, 75, 25, 195, 123, 71, 133, 198, 103, 2, 169, 52, 8, 149, 68, 220, 132, 39, 183, 158, 132, 105, 77, 48, 18, 243, 211, 178, 144, 109, 73, 36, 254, 215, 175, 134, 92, 49, 5, 216, 170, 123, 75, 26, 232, 181, 129, 76, 22, 223, 167, 110, 52, 249, 189, 128, 66, 3];
inputBytes = [49, 46, 48, 53, 51, 46, 48, 46, 55, 52, 51, 48, 52, 50, 49, 54, 65, 45, 67, 51, 68, 70, 45, 52, 55, 48, 66, 45, 66, 68, 67, 48, 45, 67, 57, 57, 55, 48, 54, 67, 51, 48, 65, 65, 69, 49, 46, 48, 53, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 65, 80, 73, 48, 101, 112, 97, 108, 101, 110, 122, 117, 101, 108, 97, 50, 64, 105, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 112, 97, 114, 107, 105, 110, 103, 46, 99, 111, 109, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 49, 48, 48, 48, 55, 49, 51, 54, 49, 51, 53, 46, 46]
        byte[] hash = new HMACSHA256(_normKey).ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        if (hash.Length >= 8)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = hash.Length - 8; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            strRes = sb.ToString();
        }
```

Here is the code of Reactjs

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(_normKey.toString(), inputBytes.toString());
console.log(hash)
```

When I pass _normkey and inputBytes without toString, It throws error key.clamps is not a function

Comment: *results are not equal* - so you have already js code? Then show it, including input and results, then it's easier to find out what's wrong.

Comment: _normkey = [150, 68, 231, 118, 4, 194, 153, 75, 25, 195, 123, 71, 133, 198, 103, 2, 169, 52, 8, 149, 68, 220, 132, 39, 183, 158, 132, 105, 77, 48, 18, 243, 211, 178, 144, 109, 73, 36, 254, 215, 175, 134, 92, 49, 5, 216, 170, 123, 75, 26, 232, 181, 129, 76, 22, 223, 167, 110, 52, 249, 189, 128, 66, 3]

Comment: inputBytes = [49, 46, 48, 53, 51, 46, 48, 46, 55, 52, 51, 48, 52, 50, 49, 54, 65, 45, 67, 51, 68, 70, 45, 52, 55, 48, 66, 45, 66, 68, 67, 48, 45, 67, 57, 57, 55, 48, 54, 67, 51, 48, 65, 65, 69, 49, 46, 48, 53, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 65, 80, 73, 48, 101, 112, 97, 108, 101, 110, 122, 117, 101, 108, 97, 50, 64, 105, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 112, 97, 114, 107, 105, 110, 103, 46, 99, 111, 109, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 49, 48, 48, 48, 55, 49, 51, 54, 49, 51, 53, 46, 46]

Comment: hash length is 32 in .net core

Comment: Check Post again. I've added react code

Comment: `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256()` does not process byte arrays but `WordArray`s. Byte arrays can be converted into _typed arrays_, which can be passed _directly_ to `WordArray.Create()`, [here](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/test/lib-typedarrays-test.js). Alternatively, _explicit_ conversions can be done, [here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1) or conversions into hex (or base64) encoded strings, which in turn can be converted into `WordArray`s using the appropriate CryptoJS [encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders).

Comment: Not getting the same result. here is my code var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(_normKey, CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(inputBytes)); var hashInBase64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64 );
                    hashInBase64 = bytes(hashInBase64);

Comment: I am getting this result : (44) [84, 113, 88, 70, 67, 75, 90, 87, 98, 110, 89, 107, 66, 85, 80, 52, 47, 114, 66, 118, 49, 70, 100, 51, 101, 43, 79, 86, 83, 99, 81, 66, 90, 68, 97, 118, 50, 109, 88, 83, 77, 119, 52, 61] while i need (32) [212, 2, 50, 4, 7 , ..... ]

Comment: Why should this work? Where is the conversion to a typed array of `inputBytes`? The conversion of `_normKey` is completely missing.

Comment: Here is the convertion of byte array   byteArrayToWordArray(ba) {
        var wa = [],
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
            wa[(i / 4) | 0] |= ba[i] << (24 - 8 * i);
        }
    
        return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(wa, ba.length);
    }

Comment: var key = this.byteArrayToWordArray(_normKey);
                    var message = this.byteArrayToWordArray(inputBytes);var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(key, message); var hashedArr = this.wordArrayToByteArray(hash, 32)

Comment: Here is my code and i am using same functions that i called from this link https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1

Comment: Now i am getting same length but different values (32) [20, 18, 179, 79, 78, 134, 208, 233, 223, 139, 229, 117, 88, 83, 242, 61, 186, 164, 255, 179, 12, 117, 60, 122, 224, 177, 18, 93, 212, 68, 44, 62]

Comment: I' ve posted a possible implementation, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the C# code is:

```
79E024C70ABA8B39
```

CryptoJS cannot process arrays directly, only `WordArray`s:

- `_normkey` and `inputBytes` can be converted to typed arrays. A typed array can be used as an argument of `WordArray.create()` and thus converted into a `WordArray`.
- `HmacSHA256()` returns a `WordArray` that can be converted to a hex string using the [hex encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) of CryptoJS. This encoding corresponds to the encoding used in the C# code. If needed the hex string can be converted to an array, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356351/9014097).

A possible implementation is:

```js
var _normkey = [150, 68, 231, 118, 4, 194, 153, 75, 25, 195, 123, 71, 133, 198, 103, 2, 169, 52, 8, 149, 68, 220, 132, 39, 183, 158, 132, 105, 77, 48, 18, 243, 211, 178, 144, 109, 73, 36, 254, 215, 175, 134, 92, 49, 5, 216, 170, 123, 75, 26, 232, 181, 129, 76, 22, 223, 167, 110, 52, 249, 189, 128, 66, 3]
var inputBytes = [49, 46, 48, 53, 51, 46, 48, 46, 55, 52, 51, 48, 52, 50, 49, 54, 65, 45, 67, 51, 68, 70, 45, 52, 55, 48, 66, 45, 66, 68, 67, 48, 45, 67, 57, 57, 55, 48, 54, 67, 51, 48, 65, 65, 69, 49, 46, 48, 53, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 65, 80, 73, 48, 101, 112, 97, 108, 101, 110, 122, 117, 101, 108, 97, 50, 64, 105, 110, 116, 101, 103, 114, 97, 112, 97, 114, 107, 105, 110, 103, 46, 99, 111, 109, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 49, 48, 48, 48, 55, 49, 51, 54, 49, 51, 53, 46, 46]

var normKeyWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(_normkey));          // Convert into WordArray via typed array
var inputBytesWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(inputBytes));

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
      inputBytesWA,
      normKeyWA
);

var last8BytesWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(hash.words.slice((32 - 8) / 4));
var last8BytesHex = last8BytesWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).toUpperCase();        // Convert into hex encoded string using CryptoJS's Hex encoder
var last8BytesArray = hexToBytes(last8BytesHex);                                  // Convert into array

console.log(last8BytesHex);
console.log(last8BytesArray);

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356351/9014097
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
    return bytes;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, the conversion between array and `WordArray` can be done *explicitly*, e.g. with the implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1).

Comment: Thanks for help. But i need this AE05A4804683AA0B ansert

Comment: Thank you alot. You really saved my life.